# Is cycling in my DNA?

Tags: commuting-bike, fitness

This is not meant to come across ignorantly or demeaning to other people I've cycled past.

When I come across other cyclists in long or short rides, I feel like I'm holding back to save hurting their feelings. It doesn't matter if they are commuters or group riders with rapha jerseys and bikes I can't afford. I have a used [Bianchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_(company)) that I got for £500 from a colleague at work. So it's nothing to write home about and is a very basic gear setup. It's a hybrid bike.

For example, there was a solo rider on my way to work and he looked to be putting in an effort on a climb. I didn’t get too much of a look at the bike, but it looked like a giant TCR. And he wore the normal cycling bib and jersey. I was wearing baggy joggers and somewhat loose jacket. I don’t know how long he's been riding nor the amount of time he has been riding for this specific ride. I got past him in no time and never saw him again after that.

Before I got my bike I walked everywhere. At the gym I could easily lift a massive weight with my legs. My legs have always been "big" and it wasn't due to my weight.

Sorry, I'm kind of stressing myself out about this. **Do I have above average cycling legs unintentionally or did I just happen to condition my legs to be this way?** Is it genetically a thing? None of my family have ever cycled, but yet I can go past everyone I meet in the streets that are cycling.

Before anyone says anything, I am not putting effort in to go past anyone; I'm going at my normal pace.

Comment: Is there a test for *"Increased hepatic gluconeogenesis: "* ? [pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16797860/)

Comment: Some people have put in 300-700km at pace in the 6days prior to you overtaking them. If slower, just assume they're on thier 160th km for the day ‍♂️

Comment: Sign up for Strava, find some local segments and try for the KOM. You answer will come fairly quickly.

Comment: @mattnz: Good (and cheap) idea. Strava also estimates power output. But for KOMs it really depends on the riders in OP’s area and how much effort they put into getting KOMs.

Comment: @Michael Absolutely, there are easy KOMs and impossible ones. The hard ones are usually big climbs where even professional sprinter might be out of luck. Those short sprinty segments strongly depend on whether someone actually goes for it or not.

Comment: Politely, this is the most impressive Humblebrag I've seen lately.  Keep working to better yourself and surpass your own times.  When you feel ready, try entering a local bike race that suits you and your preferred riding.  Most races have some way to account for new riders to make the sport more accessible.  Put yourself out there and give it a go.

Comment: Is this a genuine question or are you fishing for red herrings? If genuine how long are you long rides?

Comment: @Criggie I just read this again, and honestly it comes across as simple "cat 6 cyclist" bragging.  Until you get a license, pin on a number, actually race, and get **dropped** like every first-time racer not on his way to being a pro, you don't know what fast is.  The cyclists who he's "holding back to save hurting their feelings" probably don't care how fast this (person) is riding.

Comment: Evreybody - that yellow rider is unrelated, let's avoid him and focus on OP and the question at hand.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - It could also be someone new to cycling who is just also trying better understand the sport. Sure the question could have been better written, but your answer comes off rather crass. Are you yourself a Category racer speaking from first hand experience? If so, perhaps construct a meaningful answer that helps educate the OP rather than you a version of you suck in the comments.

Comment: @TudeProductions do feel free to join [chat] to stop this Q&A getting all tangential and divergent.

Comment: What does cycling past someone... have to do with cycling?  Maybe focus more on what *you* enjoy, rather than how you think you compare to strangers.

Comment: It's not that you pass someone or get passed. The most annoying thing is when you're just riding along and someone decides it's race time, overtakes you, slows down, overtakes you again and finally after demonstrating utter lack of riding skills settles for drafting at half meter distance.

Comment: I mean, I pass a lot of people on my way to work.  But it's not just because I like to ride fast.  It's because a lot of them are _intentionally_ not riding fast so they don't arrive at work dripping with sweat.  (I go shower at a fitness club before work so that I can ride fast and still not arrive dripping with sweat.)  It's quite possible that many of those people could pass me if they weren't focused on going slow enough not to perspire profusely.

Comment: related reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_mentality

Comment: @Kyralessa exactly I agree 100%.  sometimes (pre-covid) I liked to ride fast.  Other times I like to see how far I could ride no handed.  Still other times, I liked to enjoy the scenery.  If you passed me, I never took that as a statement on our relative worth.  We are both awesome!

Comment: Aside, there is a Stackexchange Strava club at https://www.strava.com/clubs/SEBicycles  Feel free to join up and compare.

Answer (score 16):

If you really want to find out, look for a local time trial route and see what people can do on that.

There's also an advantage coming up behind someone - not so much the aero advantage as you have to get close for that, but the knowledge that there's someone to catch up with - your head goes into race mode, even just a little, but theirs doesn't.

Some riders have all the gear but no fitness. Others are having off days. I've seen the effects you note from both sides. Within the last few days I've blasted past 2 roadies uphill while on my shopping bike with a big backpack, and struggled to make much headway at all on my faster but still heavy bike after wearing myself out earlier in the ride (140km with some rough gravel). Flat out on the TT course near me I might average 21mph for half an hour, commuting on the same bike little more than half that unless I'm rushing to get somewhere. But my fast pace would be almost last looking at events on that course; winners are 50% faster than me.

Answer (score 13):

Daniel, what is your actual question? Us strangers on the internet cannot tell you if you are genetically gifted, you must test your biology yourself.

I guess the best you can expect from this community is to suggest such tests to you:

- VO2 max
- red blood cell count
- levels of hepatic gluconeogenesis
- hematocrit level

*Community members, please add to and edit this list of genetic tests.*

Any of these tests could tell you whether you have genetic strengths regarding cycling.

But, the fact you came to the internet to rant about all your "stress" from overtaking commuters, suggests that you may be more interested in the competitive man versus man aspect of cycling, rather than just knowing whether you have some certain set of genetics.

So you should get a speedometer or an app which can serve as such, Strava being the best choice because it is built with cyclists in mind and will let you directly compare times and review rides.

Once you are able to track your speeds and your distances, then you will know where you lie in the world of cycling.

Answer (score 10):

Get a power meter or borrow a bike with one.

Bicycling is all about power in relation to your body weight and aerodynamics. Measuring your watts per kg will answer your question. Don’t just measure your maximum power (sprint) but measure at least a 20 minute effort.

There are a lot of reasons why seemingly fit riders might ride slow: Easy training ride, casual group ride, injury, long&slow training ride etc. Don’t assume that everyone you meet is in race mode ;)

The same applies the other way around: Somebody doing two minute interval training can pass you at twice your speed going up a hill. But they are only doing that for two minutes.

Answer (score 5):

Daniel I can understand what you are trying to say.

I have an entry level road bike (2019 Trek Domane SL5, No aero wheels/bars), usually ride in basketball shorts, and a cheap T-shirt while being able to hit 25 MPH or more.

Here is me with my basketball shorts on a normal ride not trying to do anything different for the camera (Full disclosure I have the camera to capture road incidents as I primarily ride on the roads. Sometimes the footage is interesting enough to share):

With that said there are circuit racers that will ride 35 MPH+ on flats and can hit above 40 MPH on flats. That blows my mind.

Here is also an olympic cyclist powering a toaster to also provide some context.

So back to you, without knowing stats like what FTP you are putting out, avg. speed, age, how far you can ride, goals, etc. it is hard to say if you are above average.

You could use an app like Strava to ride a route that others have ridden and see if you can ride it faster. I personally like to try to focus on beating my own PRs vs. trying to ride someone else's ride, but to each is their own. This may be a way for you to compare your fitness with others short of doing a race.

You could also get a power meter, see the power you are putting out over a set amount of time, and then compare that to the pros along with using it to help train.

**Bigger picture, I would suggest this for you:**

- There are riders who are faster and better climbers than you and me. So think about what they are thinking when they pass or do not pass us. Also, think about age differences too. I know some riders 1.5 times my age that probably are faster than me for various reasons, but some may also be slower. Also, you many not know how far the other riders have ridden when you are passing them. My ride speed for a 50-75 mile ride is slower than for a 25 mile short ride, and I am probably not going to go race someone in the middle of the ride just to prove a point at the risk of not being able to hit my distance goal. So some of those people in full kit may just be pacing themselves.
- I would not concern yourself with other riders who are not in your riding group. Pass them if you want, wave to them, make friends, whatever.
- If you do ride in a group and you happen to be the fastest person, don't leave someone behind. Part of riding in a group is working together and staying as a group for the whole ride vs. leaving someone miles behind. Honestly, I get good training riding with slow riders too and the slower riders benefit by being pushed by faster riders. I usually can either work on base miles or I push a much harder gear at low cadence to do strength work when riding in a slower group. Now if riding that slow bothers you, then you should find another group that is faster to ride with or ride alone. However, don't be that guy or gal that is like I am going to try to ditch another rider just to show off.

Hopefully that gives you some perspective on things.

Comment: The Olympic video was made as a statement for reducing electricity and petrol usage. If you're not trying to power a specific toaster, you can set a newspaper on fire in about 15 seconds with a bicycle and some toaster wire connected via a DC motor. I have distilled half a litre of water with a homemade BSO contraption. (I feel like I sweated more than half a litre in the process, though.) And I'm nowhere near as fit as you.

Comment: @ Michael - Yea I primarily put the olympic cyclist on there as an upper reference point in muscular size of an above average bicyclist.

Comment: Remember that the person you are about to pass may already be 100 km into their ride, or is doing intervals.

Comment: @EricS Yea I once had a guy on a 12k madone sprint out of his driveway to pass me when I was on the back end of 40 miles and that is why I don’t assume just cause I pass someone I am faster than them ; )

Comment: Good points, although to be fair, $3700CAD is not really an “entry level bike”. It’s definitely not the same caliber as OP’s $500 hybrid.

Comment: @MaplePanda It  is the entry level 105 groupset bike at the time for Trek. In 2019, it was $2200. Since then Trek spaced out their line up and added one more Domane (SL4-Tiagra) in between for 2020/2021 to fill the $2200 spot, which pushes the SL5 up closer to $2600 to get 105 components. The OP is talking about a used bike. I doubt my bike right now is worth $2200. When I was shopping for mine a full carbon used Giant TCR was $700. I guess the overall point is with training you can go fast and there will probably be people faster than you, along with reasons other riders don't race you back.

Comment: @TudeProductions I once passed the same person four times within a couple of miles. Of course the other cyclist was doing intervals and passed me four times too.

Comment: You sailed right through that stop sign at 0:51.

Comment: @EricS, yes good point regarding intervals. I also learned that often people riding slow on TT bikes in full aero tuck (like seemingly *all* of them), are often just getting used to the hunched position again after having been riding road for so long.

Comment: @msh210 - No, I pedaled through it ; )

Comment: *being able to hit 25 MPH or more*  Umm, we can see the grade on your video.  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I am aware of that as I made the overlay ; ) and again that is a portion of a normal 30 mile ride  on roads with varying inclines + traffic vs. me trying to PR for the camera. I suppose the point I was getting at was when you think you are going fast there are people faster than you and then faster than those people are more people including potential world class athletes. Natural gifts can help get you started, but consistent training helps people progress and other riders on the road may be working on their own goals vs. being worried about being passed by a stranger.

Comment: Well, your answer comes across as "Look how fast I am ...."    Nobody who **is** fast cares about (new riders), your bike or your shorts - because they don't matter at all and it comes across as humblebragging.  FWIW, your bike is better than those of most amateur racers.  Find a real group, or even a racing team - Houston's a big city with a lot of cycling teams.  Until you ride **with** actual fast riders who are trying to drop you, you don't know what fast is.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am sorry you feel that way as I quite literally said the same thing you said in your comment in my answer that the moment you think you are fast with or without kit go watch a crit race and/or olympic cycling. I primarily ride for the fitness aspect and racing is not something on my radar yet.

Comment: Please remember comments are for clarifications and improvements to the Q/A.  If you're arguing, then put it in a separate answer.  Please.  If I have to migrate the comments to chat then they get essentially hidden.

Comment: @AndrewHenle For me I chose to pay more for carbon for longevity not racing as alu tends to stress crack. I see it being nominal over the 10+ years I will ride that frame.  A statement like your setup is better than most amateur racers is hard to respond to without it degenerating into a back and forth. I do not advocate for buying more bike than you can physically ride. With that said people who I talk to that race spend more than $2200 on their frameset and wheels. If you know of a magic combo of new parts that honestly makes you competitive for under that price, please share.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's your DNA

Case in point, a housemate of mine cycled everywhere - he had a good bike and we lived in a hilly area. His friend who was not a regular cyclist came to visit and borrowed an average bike. They decide to go on a tour of the area. I happened to watch as they set off. By the end of the street, the visitor was way ahead without even appearing to try whilst my housemate was standing in his saddle trying to keep up.

Usain Bolt with zero training would run faster than 99% of the world's population.

It's only when you compete against people who are equally gifted DNA-wise that you will see your shortcomings. That's when training is necessary.

Life isn't fair and some people are better at some things without trying. P.S. I speak as someone who is not athletically gifted. I used to come last in cross-country runs at school. I did however do well at weight lifting. Body proportions and muscle type are all important.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost all down to training. Many people don't ride regularly, even when they own a top bike and racing gear, while other ride to work daily. An untrained rider probably does averages between 15km/h and 20km/h, daily commuters average at least 20km/h in the city, more when there are no traffic lights to stop at. As such, it's common for daily commuters to always be the ones who do the overtaking.

However, if you want to deflate your head, just take a look at professional races: These guys can average in the range of 40km/h on 200km courses because they trained hard for that (and maybe did something forbidden, too). That's not just twice as fast as a daily commuter, it's actually more than four times the power output. So, unless you are averaging more than 30km/h, you are nowhere near your physical limits.

(I was never able to average more than 26km/h, but I certainly have a lot of experience in overtaking other cyclists. Simply because I fall into the daily commuter category.)

Comment: You cannot claim anything about other people's physical limits. There is a lot in the genes too and neglected training during childhooed and development cannot be reversed. Besides, even my friends from the sport club, one of whom even started in the elite category of FIS Ski Classics and wins many amateur events, do NOT normally average 30 km/h. Perhaps your area is exceptionally flat?

Comment: I think it's not just training. From what I've read I've understood that you ride significantly more than I do, and I don't have any problems averaging 30 km/h for around 100 km solo on flattish route.

Comment: @ojs Well, yeah, commuting kilometers are generally crap for building speed. With only about 1km to go before you have to stop at the next red light, your body simply does not get into endurance speed mode. I've seen the effects of that when I switched to a longer route with only two stops over 9km: I got faster quite quickly, simply because of that longer uninterrupted stretch of exercise.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, my area is almost as flat as a pancake, no elevation meters to be gained at all. And, of course, I assumed flat terrain in my numbers because hills can drop your average arbitrarily low. Only flat terrain average is comparable. Btw, neglected training during childhood is definitely not "in the genes". It's simply training you didn't have.

Comment: It is the training you didn't have but is no longer in your physical limits. No matter how hard you train, you cannot overcome that. Regarding the terrain, few people have the luxury to test what they would average an sn obsolute flat. I, in particular, have no idea what I would average. I rarely can go below 1% of average gain and can perhaps do 25-26 on short rides when pushing hard.

Comment: I get around 1% average gain too. It's just that the largest individual climb in my usual routes is around 30m, so it's less effort to just power up the hills than slow down and switch to climbing mode.

Answer (score 2):

It might be, but it's not end all be all.

Why do I think so? I'm in a bit similar situation, in that I can hang on to group rides that average around 35 km/h and ride up hors categorie rated climbs with standard 39-53 crankset. It's not training in my childhood, because I was a bookish kid, dropped out of PE class as soon as I could and got the equivalent of grade C only because I beat everyone who was not in track & field team in 2K run. It might be genes, because my sister pulls off equally implausible results in a different sport, and there have been a few national level athletes in my father's family.

EDIT: Other answer reminded me of a classmate that I had in grade school. He was known to be fast, but nobody knew how fast since nobody could keep up with him. I had bought a bike computer, so he asked to borrow my bike, rode around the block and came back with top speed above 50 km/h. My other classmate said he could have cheated by shaking the magnet in front of sensor, so he did again so that we saw it. To reiterate, he was 12 years old on 3-speed bike. I used to think that I'm normal and that's what talented means.

How to confirm it? Find out the local time trial route and do a self-timed run. If there are open weekly time trials, try participating. Join group rides (but read up on group ride etiquette and pay attention to what others do). See how your results develop. Find out if there have been athletes in your family. The other answers have already covered why passing someone doesn't mean a thing, and they are right about it.

What to do about it? There's no shortcut to success. If think about serious competition, remember that you're up against people who have the same mutations and lifetime of training behind them. It's not impossible to start later in life, but manage your expectations, prepare to dedicate all of your free time to exercise and decide if it's worth it.